# send email based on an html+php template

Tags: php, html, email, templates

I'm developing a PHP web app in which I need to send e-mails in HTML format.I'm using mail() function. 
I want to send email based on a template file. This file is an html file in which I embed pieces of PHP code.
I'm having problem interpreting this template and outputting the result into a string variable that will be passed to mail() function.

```
    function get_include_contents($filename) {
        if (is_file($filename)) {
            ob_start();
            include $filename;
            return ob_get_clean();
        }
        return false;
    }

    $mesaj_confirmare_cont = get_include_contents('../Anunturi-Lemn/signup/confirmation_email.html');
```

I use some variables in the caller script to be echoed in the template file, but they are not propagated in the included $filename.
Why is that and how can I acomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

The variable needs to be passed into the function

```
function get_include_contents($filename, $my_first_var, $second_var) {
...
}

 $mesaj_confirmare_cont = get_include_contents('...confirmation_email.html', $my_first_var, $second_var);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
 file_get_contents();
```

or

```
fread();
```

in some servers `file_get_content` might be blocked so checkout you server configuration and use

Above step will give you content of file in a string

they you can use `preg_replace` and or other string function to manipulate it

Comment: I don't want preg_replace, I want php to do the replacing <?=$foo;?> like this.

Comment: PHP is a templating language. Based on a template it generates html documents. I want the generated document to be outputed in a stringand passed to mail() function, instead of sent to browser.

Comment: But the variables won't be available in the scope of your function get_include_contents() unless you add them to the global scope, which in general is bad practice. So for that reason you should add the variables as function arguments, as you can see in my example above.